# Logstash inserting dates as strings instead of dateOptionalTime

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have an Elasticsearch index with the following mapping:

```
"pickup_datetime": {
     "type": "date",
     "format": "dateOptionalTime"
}
```

Here is an example of a date contained in the file that is being read in
`"pickup_datetime": "2013-01-07 06:08:51"`

I am using Logstash to read and insert data into ES with the following lines to attempt to convert the date string into the date type.

```
  date {
    match => [ "pickup_datetime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    target => "pickup_datetime"
  }
```

But the match never seems to occur.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add `--debug` to your logstash command line and paste some relevant output so we can see what the date filter outputs?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the `date` filter was before the `csv` filter, where the columns get named, hence the `date` filter was not finding the `pickup_datetime` column since it had not yet been named.
It might be a good idea to clearly mention the sequentiality of the filters in the documentation to avoid others having similar problems in the future.